# Can I open dot Net MVC project in VS 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

We have a very old legacy system which was developed using `MVC1` through Visual Studio. Since then , Visual Studio also evolved and so has `MVC`.

Now we want to make our `MVC1 project` compliant with `MVC5`. Is there any, **ready made tool** available for this?

Various forums suggest to gradually move the project from `MVC1 to MVC2`, then from `MVC2 to MVC3` and so on.

But I was not able to find any way of converting from `MVC1 to MVC2`. Although the information regarding the same is still available, but the *tool* to convert `MVC1 to MVC2` is not found.

Can any one please throw some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old version of [ASP.NET Project upgrade tool](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008) as the limitation is

***The tool does not support Visual Studio 2008 solutions, MVC 1 projects, or projects targeting .NET 3.5. If you have a MVC 1.0 project you can use the old version of this tool to convert it to MVC 2.***

You can also manually upgrade to MVC 3

The [white paper steps](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes) for upgrading MVC1.0 to MVC2.0 are

- Fiddle with web.csproj
- Replace Version=1.0.0.0 in web.config by Version=2.0.0.0
- Reference System.Web.Mvc (v2.0.0.0) in the project
- chnange bindingRedirect in web.config
- update css and js files